# Cannot get error count in CodeMirror editor

Tags: wordpress, codemirror

Is there any way to access the number of errors in code mirror editor. Is it have something to do with lint ?

I created an instance using

```
var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#my_textarea'), my_var.cm_settings);
```

I can take the value using

```
editor.codemirror.getValue();
```

But this returns the value in editor including the code with error. Is there any function or option to get count of errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab your editors wrapper and count how many errors there are by `.length`.

Find the errors by their class name `.CodeMirror-lint-marker-error`

```
var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#my_textarea'), my_var.cm_settings);
var errors = codeEditor.find('.CodeMirror-lint-marker-error');
console.log(errors.length);
```

Or, use `editor.state.lint.marked` to receive an array of the errors.

```
var editor = wp.codeEditor.initialize($('#my_textarea'), my_var.cm_settings);   
var error_array = editor.state.lint.marked;
console.log(error_array.length);
```

Comment: I have tried this. But rejected since this is something related to dom element length. I have this as alternate solution if there is no other solution

Comment: No. This is not working. what is `$(this).closest('.content')` ? i am getting `0` on checking length of `.content`

Comment: I only get this `0: "CodeMirror-lint-markers"`
`1: "CodeMirror-linenumbers"` when i try to do `options.gutters` in my editor instance